# HTML formatting in TextMate (automatic 'outdenting')

Tags: textmate, indentation, html-editor, auto-indent

I'm using TextMate and indentation isn't working as I'd expect - more specifically, it doesn't 'outdent' closing tags for me.

I create a new HTML file, I move the cursor down to the body section ... and I type

```
<ul>(newline)
```

It appropriately indents the next line for me so I build the following

```
<ul>
    <li>hello
        </li>
        </ul>
```

Clearly, the closing tags "could" be outdented to line up with their start tags. I'm surprised TextMate doesn't do this automatically. Am I missing something? Sometimes I like to type my opening and closing tags and then fill-in the blanks ... but I keep getting this:

```
<div>
    </div>
```

It indents correctly - but it doesn't understand that this is a closing tag -- which means I've got to move the cursor behind the closing tag and outdent it myself.